# Dynamic range in chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a chart of my table, but I keep adding rows to it.

Is there a way to define the chart's Series/X-Axis/Range as part of a formula?

I want the graph to grow as my table grows - dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it depends upon the chart type chosen (which you have not mentioned) but incorporating blank rows into the initial selection allows for future expansion. In effect, instead of *growing* as more data is added, the graph *shrinks* down to a size to match the data - so as more data is added it just shrinks less.

[image: Basic chart]

[image: Add date]

[image: Add value]